# Optimizing taxonomyTerm request

Tags: 2013, javascript

I'm working on a custom navigation webpart for SP2013 using the JSOM.

Currently, a part of fetching the data from the termstore involves fetching all the terms and then getting data from the respective taxonomy terms:

```
context.load(term, ['Title', 'FriendlyUrlSegment', 'Terms', 'Parent']);
taxonomyTerm = term.getTaxonomyTerm();
context.load(taxonomyTerm);
```

Later on in the code I can access the data from the taxonomy term via

```
taxonomyTerm.get_objectData().get_properties().CustomProperties;
```

This brings me to two questions:

- Is this the right way to ask for the properties I want from the taxonomy term?
- How can I optimize the above request by specifying the fields I'm after for the taxonomy term, how can I see what options I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [SP.Taxonomy.Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) exposes [CustomProperties property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269582.aspx) you could replace the line:

```
taxonomyTerm.get_objectData().get_properties().CustomProperties;
```

with this one:

```
taxonomyTerm.get_customProperties()
```

In order to optimize the request, you could specify explicitly what properties to retrieve for [SP.Taxonomy.Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) object via [SP.ClientContext.load method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903.aspx), for example:

```
context.load(taxonomyTerm,['CustomProperties','Name']);
```